# Why isn't the size of a record equal to the sum of the sizes of its fields?

Tags: delphi, sizeof

I have next code:

```
type TRecord1 = record
  myarr: array [0..31] of single:
end;
type TRecord2 = record
  b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6: byte;
end;
type TRecord3 = record
  myarr: array [0..31] of single:    
  b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6: byte;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: Tobject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(SizeOf(TRecord1))+'+'+IntToStr(SizeOf(TRecord2))+
      '='+IntToStr(SizeOf(TRecord3)));
end;
```

The program shows the following message:

```
128+6=136
```

Why is `SizeOf(TRecord3)` equal to 136 rather than 134?

Comment: rule of thumb: if you are planning to use some structures with files - declare them as `packed`.

Comment: My rule of thumb would be never to write binary representations of records to file

Comment: Yes avoid storing binary data, but the packed directive has it's uses when records are passed during I/O (dll's, serial communication etc). Using standardized binary/string conversion techniques should be applied for new development though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to padding added because of record alignment. `TRecord3` has alignment of 4 since it contains `single` values. And so padding is added to the end of the record to make the size an exact multiple of 4. That's why the size is 136 rather than the value of 134 that you were expecting.

You can declare your record to be `packed`, or, equivalently, set the alignment compiler option to `$ALIGN 1`. With an alignment of `1` there will be no padding added to the record and `SizeOf(TRecord3)=134`. However, I strongly recommend you do not do this. Using the natural alignment results in the most efficient memory access for records. For example, it is more expensive for the processor to load a misaligned value than to load an aligned value. For a `single` or an `integer`, the natural alignment is on a 4 byte bounday. For a `double` the natural alignment is on an 8 byte boundary and so on. You should use packed records if you need binary compatibility with another library that uses packed records.

Comment: in addition, you can change the declaration to `type TRecord3 = packed record ... ` to prevent record alignment, although usually you don't need to. Aligned records perform better, but in some cases you may need packed records.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to alignment. The fields in the record  are aligned on 4 bytes or 8 bytes (or bytes when only bytes are used in the record.) in such a manner that the record when in an array all fields will keep on being aligned. If you want the formula to work you should use a 'packed record'. Please note that the fields might be unaligned and could hamper performance.